# \raisetag not working with alignedat environment

Tags: numbering, positioning, amsmath

It seems the amsmath `\raisetag` macro does not work in combination with the `alignedat` environment. See the MWE below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    \begin{alignedat}{3}
      \text{line 1} &\quad&& \text{is long, very long, really very long, unbelievably long, really it is such}\\
      \text{line 2} &&& \text{is short}
    \end{alignedat}
    \raisetag{\baselineskip} % <--- seems to do nothing!
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to fix or work around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it seems to me that `\raisetag` *should* work here.  it works with `split`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    \text{line 1} &\quad \text{is long, very long, really very long, unbelievably long, really it is such}\\
    \text{line 2} &\quad \text{is short}
  \end{split}
\raisetag{\baselineskip}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

i will enter a bug report, but can't offer any promises about when it might get
looked at (or fixed).

Answer (score 4):

Set the content using a regular `align`, adding `\nonumber` to the first part of the equation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  \text{line 1} &\quad \text{is long, very long, really very long, unbelievably long, really it is such} \nonumber \\
  \text{line 2} &\quad \text{is short}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[`amsmath.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsmath.dtx) alludes to this somewhat, but I'm not entirely sure whether it's related to your situation:

> Note that according to the current uses
>   of `\raise@tag` in e.g., `\place@tag@gather`, no adjustment
>   occurs if the tag falls in its normal position; i.e., `\raisetag`
>   has no effect unless the tag has already been shifted off-line.

Comment: it seems to me that `\raisetag` *should* work here.  there were some bug reports in the '90s, but the examples submitted were outside the intended scope, and the file was closed.  i've just tested this with `split` and it works there.  i will post an answer with that information.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the equation number be centred wrt the group of lines, the best is to use the `multlined`  environment, from the `mathtools` package. Here is an example that shows the difference with  `split` in such a context, with different way of aligning. Btw, with `alignat`, you don't have to repeat the quad separator between two groups:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \begin{document}
      \begin{equation}
        \begin{alignedat}{2}
           & \text{line 1} & \quad & X \begin{multlined}[t]
            \text{is long, very long, really }\\\text{very long, unbelievably long, really it is such}
          \end{multlined}\\
           & \text{line 1A} & & X \,\text{is short}
        \end{alignedat}
      \end{equation}
      \bigskip
      \begin{equation}
        \begin{alignedat}{2}
           \text{line 1} & \quad & X & \begin{multlined}[t]
            \text{is long, very long, really }\\\text{very long, unbelievably long, really it is such}
          \end{multlined}\\
           \text{line 1A} & &X &\, \text{is short}
        \end{alignedat}
      \end{equation}
      \bigskip
      \begin{equation}
        \begin{alignedat}{2}
          \text{line 1} & \quad & X & \begin{split}
            \text{is long, very long, really }\\\text{very long, unbelievably long, really it is such}%
          \end{split}
          \\
          \text{line 1A} & \quad & X &\, \text{is short}
        \end{alignedat}
      \end{equation}
    \end{document}
```

[image]