# How can I position the tag of a "nested" aligned environment?

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment, amsmath

I have an equation that is two wide to fit on a single line, but it has `\left(`-`\right)` split over two lines, and I can't align to something inside these for some reason...
The wanted output is something like this:

```
A = B ( C
        + D ) (1)
```

The best I can do is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 A =
 \begin{aligned}[t]
  &\left( B \right. \\
  &\phantom{(} \left. + C \right)
 \end{aligned}
 %\raisetag{-1\baselineskip} <- doesn't work :-(
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

But this places the equation number on the top line, which looks very awkward when the horizontal spacing is a lot more compact than in this isolated example.

What magic ritual do I need to perform for the proper layout of this equation?

Comment: It should be `\raisetag{-1\baselineskip}`.

Comment: @Henri true, typo, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168252/raisetag-not-working-with-alignedat-environment

Answer (score 2):

I'd do something like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{align}
    A &= \Bigl( B  \notag \\
      &\phantom{= \Bigl(}  + C \Bigr)
  \end{align}
\end{document}
```

or using `split`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
      A &= \Bigl( B  \\
        &\phantom{= \Bigl(}  + C \Bigr)
    \end{split}
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The latest will write the number of the equation in the middle of the multiple-line equation.

Comment: Please always use `\Bigl` and `\Bigr` to get the correct spacing for opening and closing delimiters.

Comment: @HenriMenke Wow... I didn't knew that! Thank you for the advise, I'll change the examples!

Answer (score 1):

Raisetag works for nested align environments if the outer scope is `gather` instead of `equation`:

```
\begin{gather}
\begin{aligned}
...
\raisetag{5ex}
\end{aligned}
\end{gather}%
```

Answer (score 0):

As `\raisetag` doesn't seem to work properly here the `align` environment looks like a decent solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
 A = &\left( B \right. \notag \\
     &\phantom{(} \left. + C \right)
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

> [image]