# Raise equation number position from new line

Tags: equations, numbering, vertical-alignment, amsmath

I am trying to write an equation in a multicolumn environment and while there is space on the final line for the equation number, LaTeX is seemingly putting it on a new line.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum, amsmath, multicol, geometry}
\geometry{left=20mm, right=20mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
Using central differences for the first and second order derivative our numerical scheme becomes
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
h_j^{n+1} =  h_j^n &+  \dfrac{\Delta t \left(h_j^n\right)^3}{(\Delta x)^2} 
\left(h_{j+1}^n - 2 h_j^n + h_{j-1}^n\right)\\ 
&+  \dfrac{3\Delta t \left(h_j^n\right)^2}{4(\Delta x)^2} 
\left(h_{j+1}^n - h_{j-1}^n\right)
\end{aligned}
\label{eqt:numerical_scheme}
\end{equation}
where we notice something\\
\lipsum[2]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

gives the following:

[image: misplaced equation number]

I would like the equation number to be higher on the final line where there is room. I have tried swapping the lines and various environments, but no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: see [\raisetag not working with alignedat environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/168252/579).  the example shows the `alignedat` environment within `equation`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,amsmath}
\addtolength\textwidth{2cm}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
Using central differences for the first and second order derivative our numerical scheme becomes
\begin{gather}
\begin{aligned}
h_j^{n+1} =  h_j^n &+  \dfrac{\Delta t \left(h_j^n\right)^3}{(\Delta x)^2} 
\left(h_{j+1}^n - 2 h_j^n + h_{j-1}^n\right)\\ 
&+  \dfrac{3\Delta t \left(h_j^n\right)^2}{4(\Delta x)^2} 
\left(h_{j+1}^n - h_{j-1}^n\right)
\end{aligned}
\label{eqt:numerical_scheme1}
\raisetag{20pt}
\end{gather}
where we notice something

Using central differences for the first and second order derivative our numerical scheme becomes
\begin{align}
h_j^{n+1} =  h_j^n &+  \dfrac{\Delta t \left(h_j^n\right)^3}{(\Delta x)^2} 
\left(h_{j+1}^n - 2 h_j^n + h_{j-1}^n\right)\nonumber\\ 
&+  \dfrac{3\Delta t \left(h_j^n\right)^2}{4(\Delta x)^2} 
\left(h_{j+1}^n - h_{j-1}^n\right)
\label{eqt:numerical_scheme2}
\end{align}
where we notice something

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Please always post full documents, I had to guess a text width to get the effect that you showed. You can use `\raisetag` (But apparently not in `equation` so I used a one line `gather`) or you can use `align` and just number one line.

Comment: Sorry about the full document, will add it in now (always apprehensive to explode the 'snippit' with what are usually long preambles)! Why did you use `\raisetag{20pt}`, was `20pt` a guess or did you work it out? Thanks!

Comment: @oliversm -- `20pt` was obviously a guess.  if you look carefully, the parentheses in the right-hand column (using `align`) are lined up, but the ones in the left-hand column aren't.

Comment: @barbarabeeton -- Thanks for pointing that out. The solution using `aligned` seems ideal.

Comment: @oliversm well also it depends on the intention if the equation had been smaller the aligned method puts the number vertically centred between the two lines (so iIused 20pt being a bit more than a baseline) it should be a bit more for that effect, if you want it lined with a baseline using aligned of multline is better as the baseline alignment of the number will be exact then

Comment: @barbarabeeton ^^

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way, with the optional argument of `aligned` and `\mathrlap`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,mathtools, lipsum}
\addtolength\textwidth{2cm}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
  Using central differences for the first and second order derivative our numerical scheme becomes
  \begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}[b]
      h_j^{n+1} =h_j^n & + \dfrac{Δt \left(h_j^n\right)³}{(Δx)²}
      \bigl(h_{j+1}^n - 2 h_j^n +\mathrlap{ h_{j-1}^n\bigr)} \\
                       & +\dfrac{3Δt \left(h_j^n\right)²}{4(Δx)²}
      \left(h_{j+1}^n - h_{j-1}^n\right)
    \end{aligned}
    \label{eqt:numerical_scheme1}
  \end{equation}
  where we notice something.

  \lipsum[11]

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For the material at hand, the equation-number-placement issues can be avoided in a simple fashion, by using a `multline` environment instead of nested `equation` and `aligned` environments. Vertical alignment on the two `+` symbols would not appear to be a compelling objective here.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength\textwidth{2.75in} % an educated guess...
\usepackage{amsmath}
% a version of \frac that uses \displaystyle for numerator and deminator:
\newcommand\ddfrac[2]{\frac{\displaystyle#1}{\displaystyle#2}}

\begin{document}
Using central differences for the first and second 
order derivatives our numerical scheme becomes
\begin{multline}
h_j^{n+1} =  h_j^n 
+ \ddfrac{\Delta t(h_j^n)^3}{(\Delta x)^2} 
   \bigl(h_{j+1}^n - 2h_j^n + h_{j-1}^n\bigr)\\ 
+  \ddfrac{3\Delta t(h_j^n)^2}{4(\Delta x)^2} 
   \bigl(h_{j+1}^n - h_{j-1}^n \bigr) 
\label{eqt:numerical_scheme2} 
\end{multline}
where we notice something
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you saying that `multline` environments should be the environment of choice for multi line equations? Is `split` just archaic or does it have advantages too?

Comment: @Kvothe - I did not claim, nor did I intend to claim, that `split` is archaic or that the `multline` environment or its close cousin, the `multlined` environment, should be the "environment of choice" for multi-line displayed equations. My answer was aimed primarily at the material at hand, for which *not* using `split` (or `aligned`, or `align`, or ...) (a) seems sensible since there is no compelling alignment point and (b) using `multline` offers a welcome extra degree of freedom. I will amend my answer to draw attention to the fact that it's not meant to be a general statement.

Answer (score 3):

Another option using `align`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\setlength\textwidth{19.18em} 
\usepackage{amsmath,microtype}
\newcommand\ddfrac[2]{\frac{\displaystyle#1}{\displaystyle#2}}

\begin{document}
\noindent differences for the first and second order derivatives 
our numerical scheme becomes
\begin{align}
h_j^{n+1} = h_j^n &+ \ddfrac{\Delta t(h_j^n)^3}{(\Delta x)^2} 
\bigl(h_{j+1}^n - 2h_j^n + h_{j-1}^n\bigr) \notag \\ 
& + \ddfrac{3\Delta t(h_j^n)^2}{4(\Delta x)^2} 
\bigl(h_{j+1}^n - h_{j-1}^n \bigr) \label{eqt:numerical_scheme2} 
\end{align}
where we notice something

\end{document}
```

[image]